# looping through objects to return objects with 'distinct' property - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, javascript-objects

I have a list of objects as shown in the image.

[image: screenshot of console.log(point) as in the code below]

These all have the property statusCode: 62467 but the journey property goes like: 0,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4

I want to loop through these objects and return the FIRST of the duplicated (they are not the same object, just that both have the same journey number and the same status code) objects with the same journey number.

So I want to return the bold objects: **0**,**1**,**2**,**3**,3,**4**,4,4,4

```
    $.each(points, function (index, point) {          
                    for (i = 0; i < journeyNumber.length; i++) {
                          if (point.k.journey === journeyNumber[i] && point.k.statusCode === '62467') {
                                console.log(point);
                                      latlngs.push(point.j.aa.k);
                                      latlngs.push(point.j.aa.B);
                          }
                     }
    });
```

The screenshot is the log of console.log(point), so ideally I would like another loop inside which returns only the first object of the same journey number.

Hope this makes sense and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var temp = [];

$.each(points, function (index, point) {
     if (temp.indexOf(point.k.journey) === -1) {

            temp.push(point.k.journey);

            console.log(point);

            latlngs.push(point.j.aa.k);
            latlngs.push(point.j.aa.B);
                          }

    });
```

Comment: YOU ARE LEGEND,     
made a few changes to your code but thanks it has worked..

if (point.k.journey === arr3[i] && point.k.statusCode === '62467') {
                                      if (temp.indexOf(point.k.journey) === -1) {
                                              console.log(point);
                                              temp.push(point.k.journey);
                                              latlngs.push(point.j.aa.k);
                                              latlngs.push(point.j.aa.B);

Answer (score 0):

Create a fresh object with status codes and check against that.

```
var journeys = {};
for(object in points){
    // extract the properties you want (or use them directly, this is not necessary)
    var journey = points[object].journey;
    var status = points[object].statusCode;
    // use the typeof operator to see if the journey has already been set before
    if(typeof journeys[journey] == "undefined"){
        // then define it.
        journeys[journey] = status;
    }
}
```

(Please note I am not actually correctly referencing the journey and statusCode, you'd have to do something like `objects[object][k].journey` to access the right property, but thats not really the point)

You can even add anything you want into the journeys object, nesting another object with the extracted latitude and longitude, or even just nesting the entire object in the journey!

```
journeys[journey] = points[object];
```

Now you can get every journey by looping through them again, and the associated first statusCode:

```
for(journey in journeys){
    console.log("First instance of journey " + journey + " had statusCode " + journeys[journey]);
}
```